# Comments plugin layout at width < 300px

Tags: sidebar, facebook-social-plugins

At the moment it looks like the layout of the Comments plugin is not formatted to accommodate iframe widths less than about 330px. I need it to fit within a sidebar that's max 235px wide.

It appears that the 'Post to Profile' text overlaps 'Posting as NAME' etc.
Does anyone have a clever hack?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to replicate this issue just now but you won't be able to fix this because it is rendered as an iFrame and cross-domain restrictions make it so any CSS changes you apply won't  work since your page is hosted on a different domain than the Facebook comment plugin.  Your best bet would be logging a bug, but I doubt it would get fixed.

Comment: thanks, I am of the same opinion... it is already listed as a bug for widths < 500px and obviously nothing is being done